# How can I tell which HubSection is selected

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I need to change the contents of an AppBar when a user changes the view in a Hub control.

The way I did it while using a Pivot control is listening to the SelectionChanged event and responding to the SelectIndex value.

The hub, however, only has a SectionsInViewChanged event, which returns a collection of multiple sections. Usually the one user is interacting with and then the adjacent, barely-visible section.

So my question is, how can I tell which Section is the one that is currently being prominently displayed to the user (so I can change the AppBar icons accordingly)?

Comment: Can you check if the first one would be the one that always works? Or maybe the middle one? Or one that has the biggest area common with the view port.

Comment: There's the [`SectionsInView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hub.sectionsinview.aspx) (combined with the `SectionsInViewChanged`) property/event.

Comment: For the sake of being accurate - you CANNOT select a HubSection. What you probably mean is which HubSection is in view the most. But even that is a complicated question to answer in a general sense.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Hub control, We can listen to the `SectionsInViewChanged` event. We can get the HubSection which is displayed in screen by this:

```
var section = hubDemo.SectionsInView[0];
```

`hubDemo` is the name of my Hub control. And we can set `Tag` property for each HubSection. For example:

```
<Hub x:Name="hubDemo" SectionsInViewChanged="demoHub_SectionsInViewChanged">
    <HubSection Tag="0" Header="Section1" Width="800"/>
    <HubSection Tag="1" Header="Section2" Width="400"/>
    <HubSection Tag="2" Header="Section3" Width="400"/>
    <HubSection Tag="3" Header="Section4" Width="400"/>
    <HubSection Tag="4" Header="Section5" Width="600"/>
</Hub>
```

So we can change AppBar content by tag:

```
private void demoHub_SectionsInViewChanged(object sender, SectionsInViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var section = hubDemo.SectionsInView[0];
    var tag = section.Tag.ToString();
    switch (tag)
    {
        // Change your AppBar by tag
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one question - do I have the guarantee that the first section in SectionsInView is the "main" one? One factor that could come into play is locale's text-direction. For example, if the text is right-to-left, it might make sense to flip the direction of the hub and get a preview of the left section, instead of the right one.

Comment: @Jan Kratochvil, Yes, the 1st section in SectionsInView is the main one.

Comment: Just remember that this is not a reliable technique. SectionsInView[0] is not guaranteed to return the main HubSection. That's because the GridView's ScrollViewer can have a SnapAlignment of Center which makes [0] the previous and [1] the Main HubSection. A SnapAlignment of Far would result in potentially the same false positive. Every app will need to decide this on their own - because, as an example, you could have 5 HubSections visible at one time - in that scenario what would be considered the "main" HubSection? It's a case by case thing, but SectionsInView is the place to start.

Comment: @ChrisShao If I try the SectionsInViewChanged event, I only get it the first time the app is started. If I change the section with touch functionallity the SectionsInViewChanged event is not fired. Have you an idea whats the problem here?

Comment: @user2025830: It looks like that `SectionsInViewChanged` is not raised if Hub contains only two HubSection.

Comment: SectionsInViewChanged will not fire when a Hub contains just two HubSections. This makes sense, since with two sections they're always visible (one full, one partially). Obviously this doesn't help when you want to determine which one is currently selected.

Comment: @Tom Verhoeff Yes, you are right. The event can't be fired when only 2 sections.

Comment: anyone seeing this event being super slow?  it looks like it takes a good second or slightly more to fire properly