# Which UserControl should I use to have similar behavior like WP8.1 Calendar app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I need to dynamically switch between weeks of year to show some tasks stored in DB in a similar way which is used in Windows Phone 8.1 Calendar app. But I can´t find the best xaml UserControl to get this behavior. I tried to use Hub with three sections, but I can´t figure out how to find out which section is currently showed(which eventHandler from section2 is raised when you move from section1 to section2) to dynamically change displayed section titles.

Any help wold be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the calendar App of Windows Phone 8.1 they're using a Pivot control to show the weeks and switch between them using swipe or clicking the item's inactive header.
Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.pivot.aspx

If you want to know which HubSection is currently in the view check this: [How can I tell which HubSection is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549059/how-can-i-tell-which-hubsection-is-selected)

//Nady