# Determine the selected HubSection in a Hub with two HubSections

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a hub control with two HubSections. When selected HubSection changes, I want to change the contents of the AppBar with section specific buttons.

Listening `SectionsInViewChanged` event is the general solution recommended to implement this behavior but this event is not fired when there are only two HubSections.

Is there another event that can be used to determine the current HubSection?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the comments to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23555602/734040) (specifically Jerry Nixon's comment)? There are times when more than one hub section are visible on the page, so which is the "main" hub section? (Put your phone in landscape mode to see what I mean.) Perhaps you could use a Pivot control instead?

Comment: Maybe test this solution http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/08/26/Getting-and-Setting-the-SeletedIndex-(visible-section)-of-the-Hub-now-with-Binding!.aspx not sure it fixes the 2 sections problem

Comment: @Depechie although the problem that arises when there are only two sections was targeted in the article strangely it doesn't solve the problem. But I might use this in combination with `HorizontalOffset` of the `ScrollViewer` in order to decide whether it is in the first section or the second. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @DecadeMoon yes I have read that answer but I will be using this behavior in a special case so I don't think that will cause a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [Shawn's article](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/08/26/Getting-and-Setting-the-SeletedIndex-%28visible-section%29-of-the-Hub-now-with-Binding!.aspx) suggested by @Depechie. I tried to implement the same solution in my app in order to update contents of the AppBar with section specific buttons.

Despite my efforts I was unable to make it work so I modified some parts of the solution. I used the behavior solution and changed only the `ScrollerOnViewChanged`function as follows. This might not be the best way or may cause unexpected results in different scenarios but in my case it worked without a problem.

```
    private void ScrollerOnViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs scrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs)
    {
        _settingIndex = true;
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
        if (scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset > (scrollViewer.ViewportWidth / 2))
            SelectedIndex = 1;
        else
            SelectedIndex = 0;

        _settingIndex = false;
    }
```

After that I added a property to my viewmodel in order to store selected index.

```
    private int _selectedIndex;

    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return _selectedIndex; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this._selectedIndex, value);
        }
    }
```

I used the behavior in the XAML in order to update SelectedIndex in my ViewModel.

```
<Hub>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:HubSelectionBehavior SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <HubSection>...</HubSection>
    <HubSection>...</HubSection>
</Hub>
```

The last thing to do was to set the visibility of AppBarButtons using this property. SectionIndexToVisibilityConverter compares SelectedIndex to ConverterParameter and returns `Visibility.Visible` if they are equal.

```
<CommandBar>
    <AppBarButton Label="Open" Icon="World" Command="{Binding OpenInBrowserCommand}" Visibility="{Binding SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource SectionIndexToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=0}"/>

    <AppBarButton Label="Previous" Icon="Back" Command="{Binding PreviousAnswerCommand}" Visibility="{Binding SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource SectionIndexToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}"/>
    <AppBarButton Label="Next" Icon="Forward" Command="{Binding NextAnswerCommand}" Visibility="{Binding SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource SectionIndexToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}"/>
</CommandBar>
```

Thanks @Depechie for suggesting the article and @Shawn for writing the article : )

Answer (score 0):

@Depechie has pointed you in the right direction.. You can use the [SelectionHub control](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/08/26/Getting-and-Setting-the-SeletedIndex-(visible-section)-of-the-Hub-now-with-Binding!.aspx) I created and add an event to it that fires when the selected index changes

```
public event EventHandler SelectionChanged;

private static void OnSelectedIndexChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var hub = d as SelectionHub;
    if (hub == null) return;

    // do not try to set the section when the user is swiping
    if (hub._settingIndex) return;

    // No sections?!?
    if (hub.Sections.Count == 0) return;
    hub.OnSelectionChanged();
}

private void OnSelectionChanged()
{
    var section = Sections[SelectedIndex];
    ScrollToSection(section);
    var handler = SelectionChanged;
    if(handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

You can extend this by adding selection changed event args to it. With this you can then subscribe to the event in your code behind and change the app bar buttons based on the index.

Comment: I have used the behavior solution in your sample. The event fires normally but `hub.Sections.IndexOf(hub.SectionsInView[0])` always returns zero (first section) when there are only two sections in the hub. Am I missing something? I believe I can use `HorizontalOffset`property of the `ScrollViewer` in order to decide which section has a bigger part in the view but I am not sure whether that is an error prone solution. By the way thanks for the article.

Comment: At the end in `ScrollerOnViewChanged` method of the solution in your article, I checked if `scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset > (scrollViewer.ViewportWidth / 2)` and decided which section has a larger part in view. I would like to write the parts I used from your solution as an answer if it is OK for you.

Comment: The event will fire numerous times and will eventually say the index of the hub with the code provided.

Comment: Unfortunately it works differently when I run it. If there are more than two sections `ScrollerOnViewChanged` event fires multiple times as you suggest and in the end the index is the right one. If I delete sections and leave only "Section One" and "Section Two", the event is fired multiple times again but this time index is always zero. As we are checking `hub.SectionsInView[0]` property and the sections in view do not change, isn't it normal behavior?